# what's the function of と here?

Tags: particles, particle-と, parsing

So, I came across this sentence in Chapter 3 of Solanin, in which the speaker is kind of philosophizing and saying random stuff while he's at a zoo with his friend, and suddenly says:

> 実はここって世界中の動物がいるかなり異常な環境で、その中に俺らはいたりしてさ…

and then says:

> ひいては虚構と異常にあふれた世の中と、それに順応してむしろ退屈な俺たちって！？

So, the problem here is that I can't understand what means the と particle in the end of「虚構と異常にあふれた世の中と」, there's no noun after it, and the sentence just continues with 「それに」. Is he quoting something?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ひいては虚構と異常にあふれた世の中と、それに順応してむしろ退屈な俺たちって！？

Let's give this part a parse.

> ひいては[**[虚構と異常に]あふれた世の中**][**1**]と、[**[それに順応してむしろ退屈な]俺たち**][**2**]って！？

- に comes with あふれる and 虚構と異常 are the things that overflow
- 虚構と異常にあふれた modifies the noun phrase (NP) 世の中, and that comes together as NP1
- それに is not the lexicalized conjunction meaning besides. Rather, it is literally それ + に
- それ refers to 虚構と異常にあふれた世の中
- That に after それ comes with the verb 順応する
- The whole thing それに順応してむしろ退屈な modifies the NP 俺たち and together they form a longer NP2
- I think now you can see the と that tripped you up is just a connective particle that connects two noun phrases:  虚構と異常にあふれた世の中(NP1) and それに順応してむしろ退屈な俺たち(NP2)

And this part connects back to the topic of the entire sentence: ここって... 虚構と異常にあふれた世の中とそれに順応してむしろ退屈な俺たち

Comment: Or 虚構と異常にあふれた世の中とそれに順応してむしろ退屈な俺たち is a new topic that would connect to something like 何なんだろう.